# menuBar submenu shadow

Tags: apache-flex, shadow, menubar

How to disable the shadow on submenu in mx:menuBar component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the `mx.skins.halo.MenuBarBackgroundSkin`, or create your own skin and add the `backgroundSkin="mySkinClass"` attribute to the menuBar.